# Stomp Client in Web Browser without Websockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, activemq-classic, stomp

I have a Node.js app in which I use [stomp-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stomp-client) to connect and subscribe to an ActiveMQ topic without websockets. My code is the same as this example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/stomp-client#super-basic-example.

Now, I want to do the same thing, but with a Vue.js application. So, I want to subscribe to an ActiveMQ topic in the browser (i.e., in JavaScript, not in Node.js). My ActiveMQ is not configured to support websockets. Is it possible to do this in a browser without websockets?

This is the error I'm getting:
[image]

Comment: How would a browser make a connection to the broker if not via WebSockets? I don't think there is any other alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is a security constraint that is part of web standards.